# How to convert from cv2 findContours to np array when there are multiple arrays in the contours?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a picture of a simple black and white mandala. I'm using Python and cv2 and numpy. My goal is to get the contour as X, Y coordinates and save them in a gcode file. The problem is that I get as the contours a few arrays with different lengths. Like this: [array([[[179,  50]], ...... [[131,  85]]], dtype=int32), array(...), array(...).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1vPI.png)
As the output I want something like this: np.array points[X][Y].

My code to get the contours:

```
 img = cv2.imread(image_path,0)
    assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

First I used this to save the points:

```
    points = []
    for contour in contours:
        points.extend(contour)

    return points
```

But I want them in np array to save them correctly and can convert them to a clean csv file.
I tried smth like this:

```
 maxlength = max(len(contour) for contour in contours)
    cnts = []
    for contour in contours:
        padded_contour = np.pad(contour, ((0, maxlength - len(contour)), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
        cnts.append(padded_contour)

    cnts_array = np.array(cnts)
```

but that gives me this error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2)  and requested shape (3,2)".

I'm a little bit confused because that should be a problem that a lot of people who are using cv2 should have and I can't find a solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
With this it works, but it makes some strange lines in the picture:

```
    all_points = []

for contour in contours:
    for point in contour:
        x, y = point[0]  # Extract x and y coordinates from the contour
        all_points.append([x, y])

# Convert the list of points to a NumPy array
contours_array = all_points  # np.array(all_points)
return contours_array
```

Output is like this: [Strange lines in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc30F.png)

Comment: You can concatenate all the arrays to get a single list of (x,y) coordinates, but then you have also merged all contours into a single one, the geometry will be broken. Also, a g-code file is a file that contains instructions for a machine, not just polygon vertices. Translating contours to instructions for how to move a machine is not trivial, you should use existing software for that.

Comment: I tried now '   all_points = []
    for contour in contours:
        for point in contour:
            x, y = point[0] 
            all_points.append([x, y])
    contours_array = np.array(all_points)
    return contours_array' and this kinda works, but as @CrisLuengo mentioned, the geometry is a little bit broken.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

cnts = []
for cnt in contours: 
    cnt = np.squeeze(np.array(cnt, dtype=int), axis=1)
    cnts.append(cnt)

## Array of Shape N x 2, N: number of contours, 2: x,y
final_array = np.vstack((cnts))
```